# .then не взаимодействует с внешней средой

Tags: javascript, promise

Почему `.then` не взаимодействует со внешними переменными: при попытке переопределить переменную внутри `.then`, внутри самого `.then` она переопределяется, но вне нет.

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(3);
});

let a;

promise.then(val => {
  a = val;
  console.log(a)
});

console.log(a)
```

Пытался сделать обходной путь - передавать в `.then` функцию, которая переопределяет переменную `a`, но безуспешно:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(3);
});

let a;

function toRes(val) {
  a = val;
}

promise.then(toRes);

console.log(a)
```

---

```js
const a = {
  get rates() {
    fetch('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
      .then(rates => {
        return rates;
      });
  }
}

console.log(a.rates);
```

---

---

---

```js
let res;
fetch('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
  .then(rate => {
    res = rate;
    console.log(res);
  });
setTimeout(console.log, 1000, res);
```

Comment: Потому что никто не обещал, что then отработает раньше чем нижний console.log. Это ж асинхронщина

Comment: Собственно, в [ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.prototype.then) про then так и прописано: если промис fulfilled, то поставить выполнение функции в очередь. А дело до этой очереди дойдёт сильно потом, после выполнения всего остального кода, в том числе после нижнего console.log

Comment: @andreymal, как можно дождаться выполнения .then? Я пробовал пихать его в асинхронную IIFE, но бестолку.

Comment: Зачем его дожидаться? Всё, что нужно выполнить при выполнении then, пишите внутри этого самого then, вот и всё

Comment: @andreymal, я обновил вопрос, добавил туда свой пример. В данном случае тоже undefined.

Comment: Геттер rates ничего не возвращает, потому и undefined

Comment: Как тогда можно вернуть в геттер rates результат промиса?

Comment: Никак. Да и зачем? Нужен результат из промиса — пишите код в then, вот и всё

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы rates был равен результату промиса.

Comment: Это технически невозможно.

Comment: Ладно, на самом деле это возможно, если вместо fetch вы сделаете блокирующий запрос через XMLHttpRequest (который остался в браузерах по историческим причинам), тем самым вызвав подвисание страницы на время работы запроса. Но если вы так сделаете, вы заработаете дурную славу в js-сообществе, да и сам браузер в консоли предупредит, что так делать не надо

Comment: @andreymal, а возможно ли вообще передать результат промиса за сам промис?

Comment: Конечно возможно, первый пример в вашем коде именно это и делает. Просто вы вызываете нижний console.log слишком рано; если его хотя бы завернуть в банальный setTimeout, чтобы таким образом дождаться выполнения then, то undefined заменится на желанное 3

Comment: Если вам религия запрещает писать код внутри then, вы можете завернуть всё своё в асинхронную функцию и дожидаться выполнения промисов с помощью await: https://jsfiddle.net/dfhqex47/1/ Учебник: https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: @andreymal, все равно ничего не работает, я обновил вопрос.

Comment: Потому что на момент вызова setTimeout значение res было undefined, вы по-прежнему не дождались промиса перед обращением к res, вот именно undefined и отпечаталось

Comment: `setTimeout(() => console.log(res), 1000)`

Comment: @Voprositel Так а что мешает сделать `console.log(await fetch('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker'))` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал вот так пользоваться промисами:
Когда вы подписываетесь на изменения `.then`, то при срабатывании просто вызываете функцию, которая выполнит ваш код

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(3);
})
.then(res => {
  promiseWorked(res);
});

function promiseWorked(res) {
  console.log(res);
}
```

Если вы хотите писать код сверху вниз, можете использовать `async/await`:

```js
void async function() {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(3);
  });
  const promiseRes = await promise;
  console.log(promiseRes);
}();
```

**НО**, пока не выполнится `await`, следующая строчка кода не выполнится в `async` функции, и если сработает ошибка, то мы это не отловим, а также весь код ниже `await` не выполнится:

```js
void async function() {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(3);
  });
  const promiseRes = await promise;
  console.log(promiseRes);
  console.log(11111);
}();
```

Поэтому, если вы используете `await`, необходимо пользоваться конструкцией `try/catch`, чтобы ловить ошибки:

```js
void async function() {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(3);
  });
  try {
    const promiseRes = await promise;
    console.log(promiseRes); // Если у промиса сработал resolve, то сработает эта строчка, но мы вызываем reject
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}();
```